# How to convert a string to integer in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, numeric, typeconverter

I am being challenged by SQL Server. I have this simple query

```
SELET * 
FROM mytable
WHERE ISNUMERIC(propertyvalue) = 1 
  AND CONVERT(int, CONVERT(decimal(9, 0), ISNULL(propertyvalue, 0 ))) > 0
```

I tried to change the conversion line from

```
CONVERT(decimal(9, 0), ISNULL(propertyvalue, 0))
```

to

```
CONVERT(decimal(9, 2), ISNULL(propertyvalue, 0))
```

or

```
CAST(ISNULL(propertyvalue, 0) AS numeric)
```

none of what I am trying is working what so ever. I keep getting this error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

EDITED

The propertyvalue has the type of `varchar(255)` and it has data like

```
2
1.5
2.1
String
1String 456
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the data that won't convert?

Comment: propertyvalue - what type is?

Comment: @jpw This, for instance: `ISNUMERIC('1e1')`

Comment: I just updated my question with ansers

Comment: Dave Gugg has the correct answer below. In your select statement's where clause, because the ISNUMERIC(...) = 1 and the CONVERT(..) > 0 conditions are on the same level they are both evaluated no matter if the value is numeric or not. The non-numeric values must be filtered first.

Comment: working for me with sample data, does the execution order of expression in AND causing this? i am doubtful

Comment: whats the expected output, i just put it in and it wrks for me also

Comment: This is really useful (values like '1e1' are the issue): http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic243646-8-1.aspx

Comment: I am not sure why one mark the question down. I hope they have a good reason to!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to filter out the string data before trying the convert:

```
 SELECT *
 INTO   #temp
 FROM   mytable
 WHERE  propertyvalue NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 

 SELECT *
 FROM   #temp
 WHERE  CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(DECIMAL(9, 0), ISNULL(propertyvalue, 0))) > 0

 DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: It is not working. I tried to do the conversion in the select as well but that is not working. I get Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: Just because you are using a CTE, it doesn't mean that the results are filtered first. Also, this doesn't take into account values like `'1e1'`, where `ISNUMERIC` returns 1

Comment: Edited to correct Lamak's first objection.  As to the ISNUMERIC "bug", I don't have a good way to correct.  Suggestions?

Comment: The real issue is that ISNUMERIC is "tricked" by values like '1e1'. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic243646-8-1.aspx

Comment: Changed to NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' to get rid of ISNUMERIC deficiency.

Comment: another idea is to use TRY_PARSE(propertyvalue as int). And the condition would be WHERE TRY_PARSE(propertyvalue as int) IS NOT NULL.

Comment: We're on 2008 R2 so no TRY_PARSE here :(

Comment: Oops :) Anyway, for future visits, idea applies to SQL Server version >= 2012

Answer (score -1):

i think it was to do with the period, it doesnt know how to convert it.

have you tried float?

```
CONVERT(float, ISNULL(propertyvalue, 0 ))
```

Comment: works for me, if you copied your query directly, you have selet and not select